# Prove a set is open in infinite norm iff it is open in 2-norm

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have shown that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\rho_p(x,y)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \vert x_i-y_i\vert^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}$ and $\rho_\infty(x,y)=\max\{\vert x_i-y_i\vert: i=1,...,n\}$,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\rho_2(x,y)\leq \rho_\infty(x,y)\leq \rho_2(x,y)$.

Now, I am trying to prove that a set $E$ is open in $\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\rho_\infty\right)$ if and only if it is open in $\left(\mathbb{R}^n,\rho_2\right)$. I can see the intuition behind proving if a set is open with the 2-norm, then it must be open with the infinite norm since the metric between two points is smaller in the 2-norm. I am having trouble forming this into a rigorous proof using open balls and a real-analysis-acceptable sort of argument. I would appreciate if someone could show me a rigorous proof using notation of open balls maybe? Thanks.

Comment: The inequalities you've noted say that each $\infty$-ball contains a $2$-ball and, conversely, each $2$-ball contains an $\infty$-ball. A set is $\infty$-open iff it contains an $\infty$-ball around every point and $2$-open iff it contains a $2$-ball around every point. Can you see why these are equivalent given the first statement?

Comment: @Thorgott I am having trouble rigourously showing how to jump from this inequality I have proved to this subset inclusion with the 2-ball and $\infty$-ball. I would appreciate if you could possibly guide me through this rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there is a $c > 0$ for which $d_2(x,y) \leq  c \cdot d_1(x,y)$, and suppose that a set $E$ is open relative to $d_2$.

Consider any $x \in E$. By the definition of an open set, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in \Bbb R^n$, $d_2(x,y) < \epsilon$ implies that $y \in E$. Note now that if $d_1(x,y) < \epsilon/c$, then
$$
d_2(x,y) \leq c \cdot d_1(x,y) < c \cdot \epsilon /c = \epsilon.
$$
Thus, if $y$ is such that $d_1(x,y) < \epsilon / c$, then $y \in E$. In other words, $E$ contains a $d_1$-neighbordhood of an arbtirary $x \in E$. It follows that $E$ is open relative to $d_1$.